# How do I get this Scanner to stop right before a blank line?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, delimiter, java-io

I am trying to get a file scanner to stop scanning when the next line is blank.

```
public static void createAudioTypes(File list, Scanner mediaReader, String mediaType) {
    if (mediaType.equalsIgnoreCase("CD") || mediaType.equalsIgnoreCase("CASSETTE")) {
        String title = mediaReader.next();
        String artist = mediaReader.next();
        int year = 0;
        if (mediaReader.hasNextInt()) {
            year = mediaReader.nextInt();
        }
        String lbl = mediaReader.next();
        ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println(title);
        System.out.println(artist);
        System.out.println(year);
        System.out.println(lbl);
        mediaReader.useDelimiter(",");
        while(mediaReader.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(mediaType)) {
            songs.add(mediaReader.next());
        }
        System.out.println(songs);
    }

}
```

Part of the text file I'm reading from:

```
CD
Immersion
Pendulum
2011
Atlantic
Genesis, Salt in the Wounds, Watercolour, Set Me on Fire, Crush, Under the Waves, Immunize (feat. Liam Howlett), The Island - pt. 1 - Dawn, The Island - pt. 2 - Dusk, Comprachicos, The Vulture, Witchcraft, Self vs Self (feat. In Flames), The Fountain (feat Steven Wilson), Encoder
16.99

CD
Demon Days
Gorillaz
```

Notice the line with all the track titles does not word wrap. This line is to be read into an Array List. Notice just beneath the line of track titles, there's a price and then a blank line. I want this
blank line to be the stopping point for the scanner, but I can't get the syntax.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

read whole line by [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) it to see if its [`isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)